# When to use url-loader with your webpack config?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

There are many SO questions on using the url-loader, but I'm wondering what exactly it does? The README is a little limited.

> The url loader works like the file loader, but can return a Data Url
>   if the file is smaller than a limit.
>
> The limit can be specified with a query parameter. (Defaults to no
>   limit)
>
> If the file is greater than the limit the file-loader is used and all
>   query parameters are passed to it.

source: https://github.com/webpack/url-loader

---

I sort of understand the README but I'm not sure when I need that functionality. I noticed a bunch of webpack configs that don't use it, and seem to still work. Is this something you need when running a server vs the webpack-dev-server?

What exactly does it do and when should I use it?

thanks!

Comment: It base-64 encodes the image directly into the css or html if below the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on my comment.

> It base-64 encodes the image directly into the css or html if below
>   the limit.

This method allows you to save on HTTP requests which can improve your page speed. It is mostly used for icons or other smaller image files. Once you start to get into bigger image files you aren't gaining much if any performance by base-64 encoding it.